# How to retrieve the IP address of the client from HttpRequest in actix-web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

Is it possible to obtain the IP address from a `HttpRequest` argument?

This is my code:

```rust
#[get("/collect")]
pub async fn collect(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    println!("collect {:?}", req);
    HttpResponse::Ok()
}
```

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "3"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not have a proxy in front of the service, it should be retrievable from the request [`peer_addr()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/struct.HttpRequest.html#method.peer_addr).

Otherwise, you can retrieve the request [`connection_info()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/struct.HttpRequest.html#method.connection_info), and from there, the [`realip_remote_addr()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/dev/struct.ConnectionInfo.html#method.realip_remote_addr).

Example:

```rust
#[get("/collect")]
pub async fn collect(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    if let Some(val) = req.peer_addr() {
        println!("Address {:?}", val.ip());
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok()
}
```

Comment: SHould I call peer_addr(req) ? I'm rust begginer, it is not obvious for me

Comment: @captain-yossarian you'd typically just do `req.peer_addr()`

Comment: @JohnLedbetter Maybe adding a security warning about the fact that ip adress returned by `realip_remote_addr()` can be spoofed.

Comment: @captain-yossarian normally in a real (production) environment, clients don't connect directly to your web server. Instead they connect to something called a "reverse proxy," which is just a different server that takes requests and forwards them onto the server you built (in which case you would need to use `real_remote_addr`). Purposes of the reverse proxy might include 1) increasing security (requests can be scanned or filtered by the proxy), 2) load balancing (distributing requests across multiple instances of your server), or 3) serving up static files like CSS stylesheets and images.

Comment: @tedtanner thank you for thorough explanation